# logic to create pop up menu in html - not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a button on my html page, i want a pop-up menu to be appear when button is clicked.
Please see the attached image.

I am not javascript expert.

Please suggest how can i create a pop up menu in html ?

[image: Pop-up menu image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dropdowns from bootstrap framework, you can check this link

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

HTML is only used to structure the page, so you can't make something appear/disappear using only html.
You will have to use javascript for that.

I did find a html 5 way of adding stuff to the context menu (right-click):
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contextmenu.asp
but it's currently only supported in firefox.